# 1980s children's short story collection with a story where a girl hatches a pterodactyl

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

Possibly from school puffin book club.

- story about hatching an egg that is actually a pterodactyl;
- another about either stepping on a butterfly or flower that produces a 'butterfly effect';
- a story about a strange girl, I think called Enid.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! Please review our [guide on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [edit] your question with any additional details you remember.

Comment: "hatching an egg that is actually a pterodactyl" - This was the plot of a [Rupert the Bear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rupert_Bear#Rupert_Bear_Annuals) story that was printed in one of their annuals. In brief, Rupert and friends name the baby pterodactyl "Terry", introduce him to a young dragon (dragons turn out to be descended from pterodactyls in this world), and eventually use a time machine to take him back to the Cretaceous.

Comment: But the stories about the butterfly effect, and the girl named Enid, don't ring a bell.

Comment: Thanks for trying.  The egg story was Def in my sci fi short story book. I wish I could remember the other stories.

Comment: It's probably too obvious, but the butterfly one sounds like "A Sound Of Thunder" by Ray Bradbury. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Sound_of_Thunder

Comment: What's strange about Enid?

Answer (score 4):

Armada SF-1 is a possibility - published 1980 and the stories were all child-safe, though they might have been aimed at teens/young adults.  ISFDB has an entry [here.](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?355713) I read it in the 90s and can't find an online version, so the following is mostly from memory.

The "Enid" story could be "*At the Bottom of the Garden*" by David Campton - A small girl talks about a mysterious friend she calls Ineed, which her mother assumes is a mispronunciation of Enid.  Ineed has furry teeth and the ability to take bodies apart, repair them and put them back together, still living.  Two different versions of this story were published:  in SF-1, Ineed straightened the little girl's teeth, fixed her blurred vision and removed all her memories of Ineed before disappearing.  The other version was published in a horror anthology and had a **much** darker ending.

"*Flap*" by Tim Stout - I'm less sure about this, but I think this is the one where a child finds an egg that hatches into a small pterodactyl.  A local biologist wants to dissect it, but the child secretly posts it to a friend in another country, who releases it in a large nature reserve.

I'm not sure about the butterfly effect one but can't remember the plot of the last one, "The Wait", so it's a possibility.

In case it helps jog your memory, the other stories I remember are:

- *The Rains of Alpha Aleph* by Julia Birley - an astronaut gets stranded on a desert planet, then it rains and the desert blooms.
- *The Lonely Robot*  by Margaret Little - a cheap household robot accidentally acquires the ability to feel some emotions and make decisions.
- *Mr. Nobody* by Rosemary Timperley - An accident victim's brain is transplanted into the body of a brain-dead man.
- *Who Is Cindy?* by Elizabeth Fancett - four girls at a school have the same name, and turn out to be manifestations of the same alien consciousness.
- *The Trodes* by Basil Copper - A quiet teenage boy always has his nose stuck in a book, and people around him disappear after seeing the aliens depicted on the book's cover.

Comment: Thank you, sounds promising